# Perl Pointers Issue with List of List

Tags: perl

I am trying to loop through a list of lists always taking the middle and then halving the list and doing this over and over.

(There will be way more to it than this, but I made this up to illustrate my struggle)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my @listylist;
my @list = (0..50);
push @listylist,\@list;
my @list2 = (0..100);
push @listylist,\@list2;
myfunc(\@listylist);

sub myfunc()
{
    my ($listgroup) = @_;
    my $f = <>;
    my @newlistoflists;
    foreach my $list (@$listgroup)
    {
        my $size = scalar @list;
        my $half = int($size/2);
        print "Size of Array -> {".$size."}\n";
        my @left = grep {$_ < $half} @list;
        $size = scalar @left;
        print "Size of Halved Array -> {".$size."}\n";
        push @newlistoflists, \@left;
    }
    myfunc(\@newlistoflists);
}
```

The Output is as Follows:

First Iteration:

```
Size of Array -> {51}
Size of Halved Array -> {25}
Size of Array -> {51}            "I am expecting to see 101"
Size of Halved Array -> {25}     "I am expecting 50"
```

Second Iteration

```
Size of Array -> {51}            "Should be 25 (half of 51)"
Size of Halved Array -> {25}     "Should then be 12"
Size of Array -> {51}            "Should be 51 (half of 101"
Size of Halved Array -> {25}     "Should then be 25"
```

I am thinking it is the pointer syntax in the foreach line, but every variation I try either gives the same result or an error.

What really confuses me is why the 2nd iteration is the same as the first.

Thank-you in advance.

Comment: Pretty much everywhere you said list, you meant array.

Comment: You shouldn't be using prototypes, and if you had `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in place as you should you would have seen `main::myfunc() called too early to check prototype`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your main code after your sub definitions, or least wrap it in curlies to limit the scope of the variables declared therein. (I do both.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );                 <-- You should always use this.

{                                       <-- Added this.
    my @listylist;
    my @list = (0..50);
    push @listylist,\@list;
    my @list2 = (0..100);
    push @listylist,\@list2;
    myfunc(\@listylist);
}                                       <-- Added this.

sub myfunc()
{
    my ($listgroup) = @_;
    my $f = <>;
    my @newlistoflists;
    foreach my $list (@$listgroup)
    {
        my $size = scalar @list;
        my $half = int($size/2);
        print "Size of Array -> {".$size."}\n";
        my @left = grep {$_ < $half} @list;
        $size = scalar @left;
        print "Size of Halved Array -> {".$size."}\n";
        push @newlistoflists, \@left;
    }
    myfunc(\@newlistoflists);
}
```

`perl` will now spot your error.

```
main::myfunc() called too early to check prototype at a.pl line 10.
Global symbol "@list" requires explicit package name at a.pl line 20.
Global symbol "@list" requires explicit package name at a.pl line 23.
Execution of a.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: Wow! That makes such a huge difference.  Nailed all the issues in about 5 minutes afterwards.

Comment: Only thing to note was that i had to prototype before myfunc because of the recursion.

Comment: @ChristenDen: You shouldn't be prototyping at all. As it stands you are saying that `myfunc` takes no parameters at all, so if you prototype it like that you will get fatal compilation errors `Too many arguments for main::myfunc`

Comment: I think you're confusing "declaring a function" (`sub myfunc;`) and "using a prototype" (`()`). You shouldn't use prototypes, and you woudn't have to declare it if you hadn't used a prototype.

Comment: @ikegami: A prototype must be applied as part of a subroutine declaration, and I think your comment is misleading. *Using a prototype* isn't just `()`

Comment: Ah but it is. Remove the `()`, and you're no longer using a prototype.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what result you want, as you're looking only at the `@left` side of each subarray

Here are the main problems with your code

- You're using a prototype for `myfunc` that says the subroutine takes no parameters. But you have coded a call to that subroutine first, so the prototype is ignored. With `use warnings 'all'` in place you would have seen

  > main::myfunc() called too early to check prototype
- Using `@list`, which is the globally-declared array defined at the top of your program. I think you must mean the dereferenced array `@$list`
- Using `grep {$_ < $half} @list`, which filters according to the *contents* of the array, rather than the indexes of the elements. Initially those are the same in your arrays `@list` and `@list2`, but as soon as you have split them once, the second half of `@list` contains 25 to 50, which is different from the indexes
- There is no exit to your recursion. Halving an array size of one will result in an empty array which is still passed back into the subroutine for more processing

Here's what I think you meant to write. I have added a call to [`Data::Dump`](http://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) to show the parameter that is being passed at each level of recursion

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dump;

my @listylist = ( [ 0 .. 50 ], [ 0 .. 100 ] );

myfunc(\@listylist);

sub myfunc {

    my ($listgroup) = @_;

    dd $listgroup;

    my @newlistoflists;

    for my $list (@$listgroup) {

        my $size = scalar @$list;
        print "Size of Array -> {$size}\n";

        my $half = int($size/2);

        my @left = @{$list}[0 .. $half-1];
        $size = scalar @left;
        print "Size of Halved Array -> {$size}\n";

        push @newlistoflists, \@left if $size > 0;
    }

    myfunc(\@newlistoflists) if @newlistoflists;
}
```

#### output

```
[[0 .. 50], [0 .. 100]]
Size of Array -> {51}
Size of Halved Array -> {25}
Size of Array -> {101}
Size of Halved Array -> {50}
[[0 .. 24], [0 .. 49]]
Size of Array -> {25}
Size of Halved Array -> {12}
Size of Array -> {50}
Size of Halved Array -> {25}
[[0 .. 11], [0 .. 24]]
Size of Array -> {12}
Size of Halved Array -> {6}
Size of Array -> {25}
Size of Halved Array -> {12}
[[0 .. 5], [0 .. 11]]
Size of Array -> {6}
Size of Halved Array -> {3}
Size of Array -> {12}
Size of Halved Array -> {6}
[[0, 1, 2], [0 .. 5]]
Size of Array -> {3}
Size of Halved Array -> {1}
Size of Array -> {6}
Size of Halved Array -> {3}
[[0], [0, 1, 2]]
Size of Array -> {1}
Size of Halved Array -> {0}
Size of Array -> {3}
Size of Halved Array -> {1}
[[0]]
Size of Array -> {1}
Size of Halved Array -> {0}
```